# wp_enqueue_scripts is not working in my plugin

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

Here is my code:

```
<?php
/*
  Plugin Name: Awesome Form Validation
  Plugin URI: http://itexpertbd.com
  Description: Use 'required' class to enable an input as required.
  Version: 1.0
  Author: Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
  Author URI: www.facebook.com/abdus.s.bhuiyan
 */
    function awesome_form_validation_scripts() {
       // wp_enqueue_style( 'awesome_form_validation', get_stylesheet_uri() );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'awesome_form_validation', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ). '/js/form_validation.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'awesome_form_validation_scripts' );
```

Its pretty simple. But after activating plugin I can't see the awesome_form_validation inspecting view page source. Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: The URL returned from `plugin_dir_url` contains a trailing slash, are you sure the URL to your file is correct?

Comment: YES. i checked again, location of js:awesome_form_validation/ js/form_validation.js

Comment: Your code otherwise works fine. Does your theme call the `wp_footer()` function to output the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )` returns plugin URL with a trailing slash (`/`). So you have to remove the extra trailing slash.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'awesome_form_validation', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ). 'js/form_validation.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
```